# Cloud Run Direct Egress (in-preview) Deployment via Github Actions causes network connectivity issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-sdk

If I deploy workloads to Cloud Run using the console, Direct Egress works fine. When deployment occurs through Github actions (using the beta client), whilst the service is re-deployed successfully, connectivity through to my VPC is broken.

Redeploying a 'broken' revision using the console without change 'fixes' the connectivity issue.

Upon comparing the revision's YAML, the only difference of note is the omission of `serving.knative.dev/route` label.

Answer (score 0):

I researched what the label related to, it appears it is an istio config element which can indicate whether the service should be routed.

https://knative.dev/docs/serving/troubleshooting/debugging-application-issues/#check-route-status

I tried setting the label from the Github Action, and it worked.

Comment: It would appear this did not reliably solve the issue.  I redeployed a config change following this reply, the connectivity between the cloud-run instance and VPC is again interrupted.

Comment: Moving the traffic from the broken revision to the working revision and then back again appear to 'fix' the broken revision's connectivity.

I am unsure whether the issue is therefore connected to the revision, or is somehow related to environment factors existing when the revision is instantiated.

I have noted however that moving the traffic to the earlier revision (without the label in deploy config), also works, BUT it now has the `serving.knative.dev/route` label set. Therefore me setting the value must have been a naïve action, and there's other environmental factors at play in.